# How to display the membership expiration date of the logged in user

Tags: php, sql, date

I am pretty novice at php and hope that I can get some help. When we register a member to our website, we register them with full name, username, password, membership expiration date which goes into a sql database called USERS. Then when they log into the members area, it displayers their username and I want to display that particular users membership expiration date before that. Since I had the session name set with username I just used a simple echo command to display the username such as:

```
 <? echo "Welcome, {$_SESSION['username']}"; ?>
```

The problem however, is the line beneath that, echoing the currently logged in users expiration date. The code I'm using for it is here:

```
<?php

                        // Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("server", "db", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `Date` FROM `USERS` WHERE username= ".$_SESSION['username'])
or die(mysql_error());

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo "Membership Expiration Date: ".$row['date'];
?>
```

I have edited this to include the code that was shared with me to get the WHERE clause.

The structure of my SQL table has 8 columns, id, username, fullname, password, email, active, code, Date, Hopefully that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Remember that if you use username as a WHERE clause, it needs to be unique! It might be better to use a user-id.

Also please secure your code, as it's easy to manipulate this.

Comment: Thank you Olavxxx. I will absolutely look into securing it, I'm just trying to get it to function. The username however is unique to that particular user.

Comment: Why is security always an after thought? It should drive your designs, not be tacked on at the end.

Comment: A fair enough question, and mainly because I am still just learning how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mySQL request select ALL the rows from the table USERS. If you want to get the row of a specific user, you have to add an WHERE clause to your request:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM USERS WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['username']);
```

I invite you to document yourself about SQL and PHP, there are plenty of manuals/tutorials available on the web.

Comment: I have been reading documentation for days to even get this far to create the user registration system, now getting into the members area, so thank you! However I had tried that code earlier, and it seems that I had misplaced a ; and now it almost works. It returns this particular error.

    Unknown column 'Qristal' in 'where clause'

Qristal obviously being the name of the user, however I assure you that record is there and that is the username. (not sure how to enter code to format this better in comments, sorry)

Comment: The error is not stating that the record is not there, it is stating that the COLUMN is not there!

Comment: Thank you for the correction, however I'm looking at it, and am thoroughly confused because the column returning the username which is in my WHERE clause is most definitely in the table.

Comment: I am at a loss because the unique username is actually there and so is the column username its under. Perhaps I am missing the obvious though the unknown column error is throwing me off.

Comment: Can you show us your code and the structure of the table ?

Comment: code edited and is hopefully what was being looked for, and thank you all for the help.